# load html page from code behind on condition

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Is possible through the code behind of asp.net to load an html page on condition?

I am now using this method with javascript in my test.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#<%= webform.ClientID %>').load('exemple.html'); })
</script>

<div id="webform"  runat="Server" visible="false"> 
</div>
```

and in the code behind:

```
if (Request.Url.ToString().Contains("https://www.exemple.com/test.aspx?action=webform_RIGHT"))
webform.Visible = true;
```

Comment: why do not you try iframe instead of div ? and you can hide and show iframe via asp.net code behinde.. by setting iframe runat = server

Comment: because what i am going to load is a "popup form", so the layer is going to be loaded in front of the page. What would have been the solution with iframe? The problem i have is that i want what javascript is doing i code behid instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a div you can use an ascx user control. Then on the page load of the aspx page you can check conditions you want and show or not the ascx control by setting its Visible property.

WebForm1.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx" TagPrefix="prefix" TagName="Ctrl" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        UC:
        <prefix:Ctrl ID="ctrlTest" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (something)
            {
                ctrlTest.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ctrlTest.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WebUserControl1.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl1" %>
User control inside
```

If you want a popup in a div you can execute tje javascript in the code behind by calling a RegisterStartupScript method. Then you can check your conditions in C# code and if they're ok you can call the script.

WebForm1.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterStartupScript("test", "<script>alert('test');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am currently using a DIV in aspx page and the visibility in code behind in the page load method. So you suggest to use what you call: "ascx user control" in c#code instead? then, i understand as you suggest i can put my javascript in code behind using RegisterStartupScript method but i dont understand when you say: "check your conditions in C# code ". The only condition i have is the one I mention above in the code behind, how can I use that in the c# code instead? thank you